# Paypal Response?

Tags: servlets, paypal, response

I have built a paypal form  like the below example

```
<form id="_xclick" name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr" method="post">

      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
     <input type="hidden" name="business" value="bussines email goes here">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="SomeTest">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">

<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.domain.com/notify.jsp">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.domain.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="www.domain.com">
```

`

The testing part is done successfully. But I don't know how I will retrieve the paypal response with transaction id of the buyer in order to change fields in my database about customer request.

Please any help how the paypal response in source code works?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to implement the IPN (Instant Payment Notification).
In your form, the notify_url is the url where PayPal will send you the IPN so you can update your database. Please take a look at the following link for mode details (it includes sample source code):

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/

I also recommend you to use, in your form, the field "custom" so during the IPN it will be easy for you to identify the payment.

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="your_order_id">
```

Comment: Be careful not to include ampersand characters in that field. It will intermittently fail in production.

Answer (score 0):

you can set paypal notify_url(IPN Response url) and success url like this way:

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://localhost/demo/payment.php/ipn_response">                                            
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/demo/payment_successful">
```

Get Paypal response paypal.php

```
     function ipn($ipn_data) {

    define('SSL_P_URL', 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    define('SSL_SAND_URL', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    $hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if (!preg_match('/paypal\.com$/', $hostname)) {
        $ipn_status = 'Validation post isn\'t from PayPal';
        if ($ipn_data == true) {
            //You can send email as well
        }
        return false;
    }

    // parse the paypal URL
    $paypal_url = ($_REQUEST['test_ipn'] == 1) ? SSL_SAND_URL : SSL_P_URL;
    $url_parsed = parse_url($paypal_url);

    $post_string = '';
    foreach ($_REQUEST as $field => $value) {
        $post_string .= $field . '=' . urlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';
    }
    $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command
    // get the correct paypal url to post request to
    $paypal_mode_status = $ipn_data; //get_option('im_sabdbox_mode');
    if ($paypal_mode_status == true)
        $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);
    else
        $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);

    $ipn_response = '';

    if (!$fp) {
        // could not open the connection. If loggin is on, the error message
        // will be in the log.
        $ipn_status = "fsockopen error no. $err_num: $err_str";
        if ($ipn_data == true) {
            echo 'fsockopen fail';
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        // Post the data back to paypal
        fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Content-length: " . strlen($post_string) . "\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
        fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n");

        // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
        }
        fclose($fp); // close connection
    }
    // Invalid IPN transaction. Check the $ipn_status and log for details.
    if (!preg_match("/VERIFIED/s", $ipn_response)) {
        $ipn_status = 'IPN Validation Failed';

        if ($ipn_data == true) {
            echo 'Validation fail';
            print_r($_REQUEST);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        $ipn_status = "IPN VERIFIED";
        if ($ipn_data == true) {
            echo 'SUCCESS';
            print_r($_REQUEST);
        }
        return true;
    }
}

function ipn_response() {
    //mail("sobhagya1411@gmail.com","My subject",print_r($request,true));
    $ipn_data = true;
    if ($this->ipn($_REQUEST)) {
        $this->insert_data($_REQUEST);
    }
}

function issetCheck($post, $key) {
    if (isset($post[$key])) {
        $return = $post[$key];
    } else {
        $return = '';
    }
    return $return;
}


 public function insert_data(){

     $post = $_REQUEST;    

    $item_name= $this->issetCheck($post, 'item_name');         
    $amount = $this->issetCheck($post, 'mc_gross');
    $currency = $this->issetCheck($post, 'mc_currency');
    $payer_email = $this->issetCheck($post, 'payer_email');
    $first_name = $this->issetCheck($post, 'first_name');
    $last_name = $this->issetCheck($post, 'last_name');
    $country = $this->issetCheck($post, 'residence_country');
    $txn_id = $this->issetCheck($post, 'txn_id');
    $txn_type = $this->issetCheck($post, 'txn_type');
    $payment_status = $this->issetCheck($post, 'payment_status');
    $payment_type = $this->issetCheck($post, 'payment_type');
    $payer_id = $this->issetCheck($post, 'payer_id');
    $create_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $payment_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $paypal_sql = "INSERT INTO ipn_data_tbl (item_name,payer_email,first_name,last_name,amount,currency,country,txn_id,txn_type,payer_id,payment_status,payment_type,create_date,payment_date)
    VALUES ($item_name,'$payer_email','$first_name','$last_name','$amount','$currency','$country','$txn_id','$txn_type','$payer_id','$payment_status','$payment_type','$create_date','$payment_date')";
    mysql_query($paypal_sql); 

}
```